# How to create an action name that starts with a number in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I want to name my ASP.NET MVC controller action as `123games` but it is not allowing me because of numeric numbers.

Do I need to use `ActionNameAttribute`?

Answer (score 13):

Yes, you do.  The [C# language specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645596.aspx) forbids identifiers that begin with a number, as per [section 2.4.2, "Identifiers"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670.aspx):

> identifier-start-character:
>
> - letter-character
> - _ (the underscore character U+005F)

Note the lack of any numeric value.

That said, you can use the [`ActionNameAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionnameattribute.aspx) to have a route with an action that begins with a number (because URLs have no such restriction), like so:

```
[ActionName("123games")]
public ActionResult _123Games()
{
     // Action code.
}
```

Note that using an underscore *is* valid for the first character of an identifier (as per the same section as seen above, and specifically below, emphasis mine):

> The rules for identifiers given in this section correspond exactly to those recommended by the Unicode Standard Annex 15, **except that underscore is allowed as an initial character** (as is traditional in the C programming language)...

So I've used that as the beginning of your method name (i.e. `_123Games`) to keep it as closely aligned in your C# code as it is with the URL fragment.